# How to list the sub-directories (or projects) from a github repository using commands?

Tags: github, svn, gitlab, git

I am new to github. I want to get the list of projects (or sub-directories) from a git repository using commands like we do as in SVN i.e by using svn list command.

Please help me.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Are these projects(or sub-directories) under version control?

You could use "git status" to list all if they are not committed and to show if you have any un tracked files you can use "git status -u" or you can try "git-ls-files" if that helps.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files